# Filter adjustment

Tags: category, filter

I have a Porto theme and I would like to adjust filter a little bit. Is there an easy way with some settings, or I should do it completely bespoke? In following picture you will find what I would like to acchieve.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should Try following the Solution I'm not sure about it's working with your theme or not (but it's working with luma theme).

- If you want overall listing page layered navigation should be in horizontal, then change your listing page layout from **2columns-left** to **1column** in **catalog_category_view.xml** file.
- If it needs for **specific category**, then set **1column layout** from backend ***Catalog > Category > specific category > Design > Layout > 1column***.

**Note:** make sure your theme is overwritten or parent by luma theme.

Comment: Thank you! This site is really useful. Answered 4 questions and you guys solved them all!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad to hear that the site has been useful for you, and I'm happy to have been able to help you with your questions. If you have any more inquiries or need further assistance, feel free to ask @XraySensei